# How to possition it the right way?

Tags: css

In the footer of the website I put two shapes,
I want them to look like this pic:
https://imghub.io/i/9L0uf

On my screen it show up in the correct place but on mobile or other screen it change is location.
Is there anyway to make it more stable like to position it from the top of the pic instead of position it from the button of the page? so it will mach with all screens?

I'm using this code:

```
.fusion-tb-footer.fusion-footer::before {
    left: -70px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 1px 0 2px #f5f5f5;
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 1px 0 2px #f5f5f5;
    -ms-box-shadow: 4px 1px 0 2px #f5f5f5;
    -o-box-shadow: 4px 1px 0 2px #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: 4px 1px 0 2px #f5f5f5;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-58deg,10deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-58deg,10deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-58deg,10deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-58deg,10deg);
    transform: skew(-58deg,10deg);
    background-color: #f6c90e;
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    height: 80px;
    content: " ";
    z-index: 999;
    bottom: 367px;
}
```

And here is my website, look at the footer:
https://zanoobia.com

Comment: HI, I'm missing something because on a narrow screen the footer seemed to be there OK. What bit is misplaced?

Comment: Please don't use external image sites to host images for your posts as Stack Overflow has no control over those images and they can disappear in the future. Images should always be imported using the features in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put your parent div .fusion-tb-footer.fusion-footer in `position: relative;`, your shapes in position `top:40px` (the value there is arbitrary) and remove the bottom attribute on them.
It will allow your shapes to be position relatively from the top of your footer.

Answer (score 0):

you can make the container of the image "position:relative"  then position those yellow shapes using "top: 0" and just  "translatey(-x%)" x=desired position this thread supposed to be comment but i dont have 50rep hahaha